# Export function with checkboxes not working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a function where users can select the images they want to download and when they click export images button selected images would download in JPG format. However I also have search and filter functions on the same page and they are messing with the checkboxes. What happens is when checkbox is clicked in order to be checked it disappears alongside with the images. Also nothing is happening when export images button is clicked. It doesn't download anything.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_email']) && $uname==$user_email){ ?>
    <div class="hello">
        <div class="w3-main w3-content w3-padding" style="max-width:1200px;margin-top:1%">
            <div class="w3-container w3-center">
                <h3>Fotoğraf Veritabanı</h3>
                <div class="search-container">
                    <form action="#imgdatabase" id="search-form">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ara">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filters">
        <form>
            <div class="top-row">
                <div class="filter">
                    <label for="teknoloji">Teknoloji:</label>
                    <select id="teknoloji" name="teknoloji">
                        <option value="4G">4G</option>
                        <option value="5G">5G</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="filter">
                    <label for="bant">Bant:</label>
                    <select id="bant" name="bant">
                        <option value="900">900</option>
                        <option value="1000">1000</option>
                        <option value="1100">1100</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="filter">
                    <label for="sehir">Şehir:</label>
                    <select id="sehir" name="sehir">
                        <option value="İstanbul">İstanbul</option>
                        <option value="İzmir">İzmir</option>
                        <option value="Antalya">Antalya</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="filter">
                    <label for="bolge">Bölge:</label>
                    <select id="bolge" name="bolge">
                        <option value="Marmara">Marmara</option>
                        <option value="Ege">Ege</option>
                        <option value="Akdeniz">Akdeniz</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-row">
                <div class="filter">
                    <label for="saha">Saha ID:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="saha" name="saha" min="1" max="10">
                </div>
                <div class="filter">
                    <label for="survey">Survey ID:</label>
                    <input type="number" id="survey" name="survey" min="1" max="10">
                </div>
                <div class="filter">
                    <label for="date">Survey Tarihi:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="GG/AA/YYYY">
                </div>
                <div class="filter">
                    <label for="surveyor">Surveyi Yapan:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="surveyor" name="surveyor">
                </div>
                <button id="clear-filters"><img src="images/filterclear.png"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>



        </div>
    <div class="imgcontainer" id="imgdatabase" style="margin-top:50px">
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" class="image-link small" href="images/pdatabase/image 6.png" data-lightbox="imgset">

            <img src="images/pdatabase/image 6.png" data-teknoloji="4G" data-bant="900" data-sehir="İstanbul"
                data-bolge="Marmara" data-saha="001" data-survey="001" data-date="15/03/2023"
                data-surveyor="Berke Ilgın" alt="4g,900,istanbul,marmara,001,001,15/03/2023,Berke Ilgın" id="img1">
                <input type="checkbox" class="image-checkbox">

        </a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"  class="image-link small" href="images/pdatabase/image 7.png" data-lightbox="imgset">
            <img src="images/pdatabase/image 7.png" data-teknoloji="5G" data-bant="1000" data-sehir="İzmir"
                data-bolge="Ege" data-saha="002" data-survey="002" data-date="17/03/2023" data-surveyor="Berke Unan"
                alt="5G,1000,İzmir,Ege,002,002,17/03/2023,Berke Unan" id="img2">
        </a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"  class="image-link small" href="images/pdatabase/image 8.png" data-lightbox="imgset">
            <img src="images/pdatabase/image 8.png" data-teknoloji="4G" data-bant="1100" data-sehir="Antalya"
                data-bolge="Akdeniz" data-saha="003" data-survey="003" data-date="16/03/2023" data-surveyor="Mert Uygun"
                alt="4G,1100,Antalya,Akdeniz,003,003,16/03/2023,Mert Uygun" id="img3">
        </a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"  class="image-link small" href="images/pdatabase/image 9.png" data-lightbox="imgset">
            <img src="images/pdatabase/image 9.png" data-teknoloji="4G" data-bant="1000" data-sehir="İstanbul"
                data-bolge="Marmara" data-saha="004" data-survey="004" data-date="14/03/2023" data-surveyor="Ezgi Diril"
                alt="4G,1000,İstanbul,Marmara,004,004,14/03/2023,Ezgi Diril" id="img4">
        </a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"  class="image-link small" href="images/pdatabase/image 10.png" data-lightbox="imgset">
            <img src="images/pdatabase/image 10.png" data-teknoloji="5G" data-bant="900" data-sehir="Antalya"
                data-bolge="Akdeniz" data-saha="005" data-survey="005" data-date="19/03/2023"
                data-surveyor="Berke Ilgın" alt="5G,900,Antalya,Akdeniz,005,005,19/03/2023,Berke Ilgın" id="img5">
        </a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"  class="image-link small" href="images/pdatabase/image 11.png" data-lightbox="imgset">
            <img src="images/pdatabase/image 11.png" data-teknoloji="5G" data-bant="1100" data-sehir="İzmir"
                data-bolge="Ege" data-saha="006" data-survey="006" data-date="16/02/2023" data-surveyor="Berke Unan"
                alt="5G,1100,İzmir,Ege,006,006,16/02/2023,Berke Unan" id="img6">
        </a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"  class="image-link small" href="images/pdatabase/image 12.png" data-lightbox="imgset">
            <img src="images/pdatabase/image 12.png" data-teknoloji="4G" data-bant="1100" data-sehir="İstanbul"
                data-bolge="Marmara" data-saha="007" data-survey="007" data-date="15/03/2023" data-surveyor="Mert Uygun"
                alt="4G,1100,İstanbul,Marmara,007,007,15/03/2023,Mert Uygun" id="img7">
        </a>
    </div>
     <button id="export-images">Resimleri İndir</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Get the input field
  var input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

  // Add event listener to the input field
  input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Get the value of the input field and convert to lowercase
    var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
    // Get all images in the database
    var images = document.querySelectorAll(".imgcontainer img");
    // Loop through each image
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      var caption = images[i].getAttribute("alt").toLowerCase();
      // Check if the caption contains the search term
      if (caption.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        images[i].parentNode.style.display = ""; // Show the image container
      } else {
        images[i].parentNode.style.display = "none"; // Hide the image container
      }
    }
  });

  // Prevent form submission on enter
  $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $('#teknoloji, #bant, #sehir, #bolge, #saha, #survey, #date, #surveyor').val('');

  $('select, input').on('change', function () {
    var teknoloji = $('#teknoloji').val();
    var bant = $('#bant').val();
    var sehir = $('#sehir').val();
    var bolge = $('#bolge').val();
    var saha = $('#saha').val().padStart(3, '0');
    var survey = $('#survey').val().padStart(3, '0');
    var date = $('#date').val();
    var surveyor = $('#surveyor').val();

    $('.imgcontainer img').each(function () {
      if (
        $(this).data('teknoloji') == teknoloji &&
        $(this).data('bant') == bant &&
        $(this).data('sehir') == sehir &&
        $(this).data('bolge') == bolge &&
        $(this).data('saha') == saha &&
        $(this).data('survey') == survey &&
        $(this).data('date') == date &&
        $(this).data('surveyor') == surveyor
      ) {
        $(this).parent().show(); // show the image container
      } else {
        $(this).parent().hide(); // hide the image container
      }
    });
  });

  // Checkbox functionality
  $('.image-checkbox').on('change', function () {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var isChecked = checkbox.prop('checked');
    var imgcontainer = checkbox.closest('.imgcontainer');

    if (isChecked) {
      imgcontainer.addClass('selected');
    } else {
      imgcontainer.removeClass('selected');
    }
  });

  // Export button functionality
  $('#export-images').on('click', function () {
    var selectedImages = $('.imgcontainer.selected').find('img');
    if (selectedImages.length > 0) {
      selectedImages.each(function () {
        var imageUrl = $(this).attr('src');
        var imageAlt = $(this).attr('alt');

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', imageUrl);
        link.setAttribute('download', imageAlt + '.jpg');
        link.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
      });
    } else {
      alert('Please select at least one image to export.');
    }
  });

  // Adjust visibility of image containers based on filters
  function updateImageContainerVisibility() {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.imgcontainer');

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      images[i].style.display = ''; // Show all image containers
    }
  }

  // Add event listener to the input field
  $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    updateImageContainerVisibility();
  });

  // Trigger update on page load
  updateImageContainerVisibility();

  // Listen for click on clear all button
  $('#clear-filters').on('click', function () {
    // Reset all select dropdowns and input fields
    $('select').val('');
    $('input[type="text"]').val('');
    $('input[type="date"]').val('');

    // Show all image containers
    $('.imgcontainer').show();

    // Reset the search input
    input.value = '';
    // Trigger keyup event to update the search results
    var event = new Event('keyup');
    input.dispatchEvent(event);
  });
});
```

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and do not know how to proceed so your help will be really appreciated. I had lightbox working before but it kept getting activated when the checkbox was clicked so I removed it. I'll edit the rest of it later, after this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since checkboxes are `<input>` elements, they're being included in this event listener:

```
  $('select, input').on('change', function () {
```

So when it does `$(this).parent().hide()` it hides the parent of the checkbox, which hides the checkbox.

Change the above line to

```
  $('select, input:not(.image-checkbox)').on('change', function () {
```

so the checkboxes aren't included.

Comment: I changed the class to id for the checkbox and with the change you suggested it worked, thanks! Also when clicking export images button after selecting just one image it downloads all images whether they are selected or not. To give an example let's say I checked the box for image 2 and 3 and clicked export images, it then downloads all 7 images, it does not matter if others are selected or not.

Comment: All your images are in the same `img-container`. So when you select the container, you download all its images.

Comment: You don't have separate checkboxes for each image, just one checkbox for the whole container.